# Visual Studio 2019 SSIS package does not run when starting in IDE (only validates)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019, etl

When I run a package in Visual studio 2019, nothing appears to happen (only validation of all tasks). When I execute one task (right-click on a task, execute), it works fine.

**Example:**

I Created one simple task-  script task. The script task contains one line only - messagebox.show("Working.").
When I "Execute Task" (right-click on task, execute), it works (a message box pops up). When I "debug" the package (Debug/start debugging, or F5) nothing happens. Execution results show only validation.

Even two very simple basic expression tasks, ie no script tasks - if I place breakpoints on tasks (before/after execute on each) and start to debug, breakpoints don't fire. Execution results show only validation.

Answer (score 2):

**TargetServerVersion property**

The first thing you should try is to change the package `TargetServerVersion` property to match the installed SQL Server version. Even if you are not using an `Execute SQL Task` or any other SQL component. This property may affect the whole package as mentioned in the screenshot below:

> Specifies the version that is used to save, deploy, execute and debug packages in SSDTBI.

[image]

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project?](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)

**Package debugging properties**

The second thing you should check is the package debug configuration. Make sure that the `StartAction` property is set to `Execute Package`. Also, if you are running the package in `64-bit` mode, try to use the `32-bit` mode.

[image]

[image]

**Running in safe mode**

The last thing to try is to start Visual Studio in safe mode, maybe a third-party extension is causing this behavior. You can use the following command:

```
devenv /safemode
```

Comment: Thank you for very helpful answer - regrettably, no luck. Having said that, I have created a brand new solution, and all works ok. Issue with existing solution. Sorry, thank you for your help.

Comment: @americano try to compare both solutions files using a text comparison tool. I may lead you to the issue's cause0

Comment: Correction to my earlier response. Changing target did resolve this. Currently targetting earlier version 2016. Basicalli I have the same issue to this ... 

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230073/ssis-scripts-in-package-part-not-being-executed-when-target-server-is-2016

Comment: trouble is, I need to target 2016, which does not work. Reinstalled SSDT and SSIS extensions, still no joy.

Comment: @americano `TargetServerVersion` should be changed only when you need to deploy the SSIS package. Design and debug the package on the working version and change it when you need to deploy it.

Comment: It works flawlessly fine for my friend who has the same (VS 2019, target SQL 2016). There has to be something else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my SSIS packages, i had some that worked ok and some that did nothing when you right clicked and chose Execute package. After creating an new version of one of them, i compared the differences and there were invalid connection in the older version.
I went back to the older version that was not running and opened the package and for all the connections in the connection manager for the package i opened and tested the connections on all.
Afterwards i could then rerun the package for Visual Studio 2019